# How do I prevent browsers from storing cookies?

Tags: html, caching, cookies

I have a webpage that plays about 15 videos at any given time. The videos change on a weekly basis, which are loaded from an external XML file.

Please look at the site here

www.hqwebvideos.com

The problem is that when my prospects view my site for the 2nd or third or fourth time, the previous XML video data is stored in their cache. Incidentally, old content is being viewed on the webpage. I want them to return to the site and load the new content each time. Basically, I want to figure out a way so that browsers will not store cookies or data in the cache when they go to my site. Any ideas?

Comment: This has nothing to do with cookies, from your description. If you don't use cookies, they won't be stored. If you do, ensure they expire on browser exit.

Comment: To those wanting to close the thread as spam: I don't see how giving a Web address the OP works on is spam, even less as it isn't even a link nor fully formed. And the question is valid.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Cache-Control http header to control how long data is cached before it expires.  For example:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=3600, must-revalidate
```

Would indicate that the cache expires in 1 hour.  You can read more about it [here](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/#CACHE-CONTROL).

Comment: How do I put that in the head? Just like this:

<Cache-Control: max-age=3600, must-revalidate>

Comment: Not HTML header, but HTTP header. How is your site written? ASP? PHP? Other?